# What is the problem with the line and the color of my objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

[image: Line Outside the color of the object]

I am using Adobe Illustrator CS6 and I have a problem with the line and the color of the objects. For some reason, they do not fit together.

From the picture, you can see that the line is outside the color of the object. If I want to move the line I do not know where it will fit. It seems like the line is the broken one.

Thanks for the support and the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check and possibly turn **off** [Align to Pixel Grid](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/pixel-perfect.html)

The only time I've seen this behavior is when [Align to Pixel Grid](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/pixel-perfect.html) is on.

I would post *how* to turn it off, but Adobe keeps moving those options. 
So it's best to check the link: [Align to Pixel Grid](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/pixel-perfect.html) 

There's much more information at Adobe's site regarding it's functionality.

> Illustrator lets you create pixel-perfect art that looks sharp and crisp on screens at different stroke widths and alignment options. Choose to align an existing object to the pixel grid with a single click or align a new object right while drawing it. While transforming objects, you can preserve pixel-alignment without distorting the artwork. Pixel-alignment works for objects as well as individual path segments and anchor points that comprise them.

---

Although that image *does* somewhat appear to be a result of Illustrators' 3D Effect. That may simply be to how you have shapes configured and the selection active.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have an effect applied to the object.

Select the object and open the *Appearance Panel* and look for an effect applied to your shape. I'm guessing it's a transform effect.

[image: Appearance Panel]

You can then remove the effect, by dragging it to the trashcan.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

I checked the Appearance Panel and there are no effects on the shapes. It seems like it is some option that I've changed in the Preferences or something similar, but I cannot find what exactly it is.

Comment: 1. Does this happen with all objects or only *this* object?
2. If you make a new layer.. same issue?

Comment: It happens with some of the objects and if I make a new layer the problem is still there.

I tried to rebuild the same object all over again and now I do not have this problem. While rebuilding it I was trying different things so that I can find out what is the problem and it turns out that the main problem appears when I try to take color with the Eyedropper Tool from a shape without this kind of problem (from a normal shape).

If I put the color in the Fill (X), without using the Eyedropper Tool, I do not have this kind of problem.